# -bash: no such file or directory for ALL commands

Tags: uninstall

I can't use any command right now in linux besides `cd`. Doing `ls`, `vim`, `shutdown` returns on of the  the following

```
bash: /usr/bin/name_of_command : No such file or directory
bash: /bin/name : No such file or directory
bash: /sbin/name : No such file or directory
```

I did something dumb on my system to start this problem (did a forceful remove of the libc6 package: `sudo dpkg --force-all -P libc6`). So now it seems as if I can't do anything using bin.

Somebody please help!!!

Comment: I doubt you can recover from removing `libc6`. I don't think there's a package as deep in the core of the system as `libc`, not even the kernel (since you can haVe multiple kernel versions installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a live USB System, boot it and connect to the internet.
Then `chroot` into your broken system and run `apt-get install libc6`.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the packages

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Hope this helps!